# Where are HW and LEO stored in Kafka

Tags: apache-kafka

I've known that there were three important metadata in Kafka: HW, LEO and leader epoch.

I know that each partition has its own leader epoch, which is stored in a file named `leader-epoch-checkpoint`. But after reading many docs, I can't still figure out where HW and LEO are stored.

I don't think they can simply be stored in RAM because Kafka broker may restart. So where are they? Are they in Zookeeper, or in some files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Kafka source，the highwatermark(HW) also store in checkpoint file，the filename is "replication-offset-checkpoint". That will reload into RAW when Kafka Broker restart.

You can see the schedule method "kafka.server.ReplicaManager#checkpointHighWatermarks",that will flush the highwatermark value to the "replication-offset-checkpoint" file.

```
// in Class ReplicaManager
// the Map for all replication-offset-checkpoint file
@volatile var highWatermarkCheckpoints: Map[String, OffsetCheckpointFile]
// method checkpointHighWatermarks,flush all partitions hw
try highWatermarkCheckpoints.get(logDir).foreach(_.write(hws))
```

The LogEndOffset(LEO) only stored in RAW, Kafka will calculate the LEO when it load the log segments.

```
// see the method scala.Predef$#locally(in class kafka.log.Log)
// really nextOffset = activeSegment.readNextOffset
val nextOffset = loadSegments()
/* Calculate the offset of the next message */
nextOffsetMetadata = LogOffsetMetadata(nextOffset, activeSegment.baseOffset,activeSegment.size)
```